# Let $A$ be a set of $n$ elements and $B$ sets of $n-1$ elements such that $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: combinatorics

Let $A$ be a set of $n$ elements and $B$ set of $n-1$ elements such that $n \in \mathbb{N}$. How many surjective functions there are, from $A$ towards $B$?

---

***My attempt*** :

We can use Pigeonhole Principle to take two elements from $n$ optional X's and map them to one $y$ in the range, then we continue to map one-to-one the other elements in the domain.
So therefore the answer is $\binom{n}{2}
\cdot (n-1)\cdot (n-2)!$. Am I right?

Comment: Why do you speak of groups here as the question seems not related to groups?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net See the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You choose one $y$ out of the $n-1$ elements of $B$, so this makes $n-1$ options. Than you pick two out of the the $n$ elements of $A$, which get mapped to $y$, this gives you the $n$ over 2. So far so good, now you just have to map the remaining $n-2$ elements of $A$ to the $n-2$ elements of $B$. To do so there are exactly $(n-2)!$ many possibilites, so your answer is right.

But why do you assume $A$ and $B$ to be groups? You do not use this in your explanation, you just view them as sets.

Comment: If A has n elements and B has n-2 elements can you explain how we find the number of functions? Thank you.

Comment: If I get your question right you want to decrease the number of elements in $B$ to $n-2$. This gives us more options since we can map three elements from $A$ to one Element of $B$ or we can map two pairs of elements of $A$ to two different elements in $B$.
We have to consider both options and add the number of possibilites. The first option results in $\left(\begin{matrix}n \\ 3\end{matrix}\right)\cdot (n-2)\cdot (n-3)!$ possibilities.

Comment: For the second option we get $\left(\begin{matrix}n-2 \\ 2\end{matrix}\right) \cdot \left(\begin{matrix}n \\ 2\end{matrix}\right) \cdot \left(\begin{matrix}n-2 \\ 2\end{matrix}\right) \cdot (n-3)!$.
The sum of both this options gives us the total number of posibilities.

Comment: Thank you. I get the point. So we can conclude a closed form formula when A has n elements and B has m elements with m<n. Thank you once again.